# Расширяем зону покрытия Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi

Имеем:

1. DSL Wi-Fi роутер (ASUS)
2. Wi-Fi роутер включёный в режиме повторителя (ASUS G32), по Wi-fi подключается к роутеру 1.

В роли DHCP и шлюза выступает роутер 1, DHCP раздаёт адреса начиная с 192.168.1.100 по 192.168.1.200
 К роутеру 2 через RJ-45 подключен компьютер(так как у компьютера нет встроеного Wi-Fi адаптера), и собственно вопрос:
 Если в компьютере вручную прописать адрес с 192.168.1.2 по 192.168.1.99 то сетки нет!А если с 192.168.1.100 по 192.168.1.200 или получать по DHCP то всё ОК! В Чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ лежит на поверхности

> Wi-Fi роутер включёный в режимеповторителя (ASUS G32), по Wi-fiподключается к роутеру 1. и В ролиDHCP и шлюза выступает роутер 1, DHCPраздаёт адреса начиная с 192.168.1.100по 192.168.1.200

то есть для повторителя разрешённый диапазон составляется из адресов назначаемых DHCP - если же необходимо использовать другие адреса со статичной привязкой, то следует расширить диапазон и привязать IP к MAC-у или имени машины, смотря что предусмотрено в настройках (прошивке) вашего роутера на котором работает DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что адрес 192.168.0.1 или 192.168.0.2, или же, как в вашем случае, 192.168.1.1 - это адрес вашего шлюза! Грубо говоря, к которому подключается ваша машина, с диапазоном от 192.168.1.100 до 192.168.1.200.

Адрес 192.168.1.1 - дефолтный адрес роутера и соответственно 192.168.1.100 - это ваш дефолтный адрес, его не нужно настраивать вручную (по крайней мере, так в linux, не знаю как в Windows).

Comment: 192.168.1.1 - действительно адрес шлюза, подсеть 255.255.255.0, соответстыенно весь диапозон адресов этой сети должен работать! Почему работают только 192.168.1.100 до 192.168.1.200!?